# Deserialize Android Layout XML?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

Whats the best way for me to take an android XML layout file and automatically generate the equivalent Java code? Does a tool like JAXB work and if so how do I use it?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Telling us that -- and providing related details, like where and when and how you would like this to be done -- would help people give you better advice.

Comment: I don't need to do this at runtime. I just want a simple way to take an android xml layout and pass it to, say, a command line tool to generate the equivalent Java. I have a few reasons why but instead of taking time to explain that I'd just like to know if its possible, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Whats the best way for me to take an android XML layout file and automatically generate the equivalent Java code?

Step #1: Parse the XML.

Step #2: Generate the Java code. You'll have to pray that you can build your own `AttributeSet` implementation that works with your generated code, otherwise this will be a very complex problem.

> Does a tool like JAXB work

AFAIK, JAXB needs an XML Schema, and there is no such schema possible for the Android layout file.

Whatever problem you're trying to solve this way, there's probably a better solution.

> I just want a simple way to take an android xml layout and pass it to, say, a command line tool to generate the equivalent Java.

I seriously doubt that this will be "simple" for any reasonable definition of the term.

Comment: JAXB does not require an XML schema.  You can start with Java objects and apply annotations to customize the mapping to XML.

Comment: Blaise, what about the reverse? If I want to go from android xml -> java then I need a schema, correct?

Answer (score 1):

It's an interesting idea, though a bit useless IMHO. Why would one want to do it? Inflating an XML is very fast operation and hides a lot of complexity - for example it takes into account what is the current DisplayMetrics and recalculates layout parameters (width/height) appropriately to the density and size of the screen... It's also very fast because it does not actually require XML parsing - parsing is done at compilation time and what is actually stored by android is a binary version of the layout which is optimized for efficiency (that's why you cannot build layout XML dynamically from an XML file).

If you would like to modify the Java code and add/remove some elements then it is much more efficient to inflate the XML and then do all the modifications -less clutter simpler code and all the calculations are done for you...